# how to use iterparse to get xml snippet

Tags: python, xml

I'm trying to parse a large XML KML file.
Inside the python script I have the following commands:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as Etree
for event, elem in Etree.iterparse("tracts.kml", events=('start', 'end')):
     if event == 'end' and elem.tag == '{http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2}MultiGeometry':
          print(elem)
```

The xml looks like this:

```
<MultiGeometry>
     <Polygon>
         <Altitude>
         </Altitude>
         <coordinates>
         </coordinates>
     </Polygon>
</MultiGeometry>
```

What I want is to export the text inside `<MultiGeometry></MultiGeometry>` to include child tags and text inside each of them.

Meaning the output is a string that looks like: `<Polygon>...</Polygon>` in a string format.

elem.text only assumes that there is values outside of the childtags.  I want all of it.  How do I get all of it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the complete string of an xml element, you can use [`ElementTree.tostring()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.tostring) function . Please note this returns a byte string, (encoded using the encoding that is passed to the method , default for encoding is `'us-ascii'` ) , you will need to `decode()` the value to get the actual string.

Example -

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>> r = ET.fromstring('''<MultiGeometry>
...      <Polygon>
...          <Altitude>
...          </Altitude>
...          <coordinates>
...          </coordinates>
...      </Polygon>
... </MultiGeometry>''')
>>> ET.tostring(r)
b'<MultiGeometry>\n     <Polygon>\n         <Altitude>\n         </Altitude>\n         <coordinates>\n         </coordinates>\n     </Polygon>\n</MultiGeometry>'
>>> print(ET.tostring(r).decode())
<MultiGeometry>
     <Polygon>
         <Altitude>
         </Altitude>
         <coordinates>
         </coordinates>
     </Polygon>
</MultiGeometry>
```

Comment: this is great. the tostring() function keeps namespaces in the string.  How do I remove them for a clean xml string?  Thanks.

Comment: @arcee123 You do not want to remove the namespaces. Deal with them correctly instead.

Comment: in my case the target application can't handle them.

Comment: Then you have to create a new output XML tree with new elements as your parser goes. Namespaces are a non-removable feature of XML nodes, you cannot "get rid of them".

Comment: That being said, your target application is broken. If you have a chance to fix it, you should fix it.